# Is there anyway to create a Linked Server in an Azure Managed Instance to a Progress Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, odbc, progress-db

I'm in the process of testing/playing about with Azure.  We have moved an on-premise SQL Server database to an Azure Managed Instance, however, this contained a linked server to a Progress database via an ODBC DSN connection.

Of course this no longer works. Does anyone know if this is possible or will I have to import the various Progress tables into Azure via a different way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't install drivers on a Managed Instance, so it only supports linked servers that use the SQL Server drivers.

As a workaround you can "double-hop" through a Linked Server on a small Azure VM running Windows and SQL Server Express Edition.  See eg [Using Heterogeneous Linked Servers from Azure SQL MI][1]

Which is enough of a pain that you'd want to load the data into MI using some external tool, like SSIS or Azure Data Factory.
[1]: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/modernization-best-practices-and/using-heterogeneous-linked-servers-from-azure-sql-mi/ba-p/3074530

Comment: ah ok, so not as straight forward as anticipated - what about Azure Synapse - can that talk to Progress 'out-of-the-box'?

Comment: The Synapse or ADF Pipelines can copy data from any ODBC data source if you use a Self-Hosted Integration Runtime. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odbc?tabs=data-factory  But it's an ETL tool, not like Linked Server.